# How can I specify arguments of export function during debugging a DLL through rundll32 using IDA pro?

Tags: debugging, dll, reverse-engineering, ida, rundll32

### Question

---

Could you tell me a way to debug an export function of a DLL with specific arguments through rundll32.exe using IDA pro?

rundll32.exe calls an export function with unintentional arguments.

### Detail

---

I used following settings in process options to debug a 32bit DLL in Windows10(x64).

Application: **C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rundll32.exe**

Input file: **C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\92D7.dll**

Directory: **C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp**

Parameters: **C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\92D7.dll, abc arg1 arg2**

---

After starting debugging, I can see the arguments passed from rundll32 in the stack.

1st arg: **Window handler return from CreateWindowExA()**

2nd arg: **BaseImage of the DLL**

3rd arg: **Pointer to "arg1 arg2"**

4th arg: **Size of "arg1 arg2"**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eclfx.png)

That's why, the export function is called as below.

```
abc(hwnd, baseImage, "arg1 arg2", sizeof("arg1 arg2"));
```

I'd like to know how to call it as the following.

```
abc("arg1", "arg2");
```

I will compile a simple binary to call it as above if there's no way through rundll32.

Comment: You should edit your question and include the full command you use for executing rundll32.exe (with all arguments in excactly the way you execute it).

Comment: I changed the command in process options from abstraction to real one.

Comment: If an exported function requires 5 arguments you can't just provide two of them. I agree with you that building an own binary is a good alternative solution.

Comment: IDA might not be able to specify arguments of exported function in process options while debugging the function through rundll32. I will build my own binary to do it as you recommended.